# LeadBolt Interstitial ad - I can not remove black background

Tags: leadbolt, interstitial

I use interstitial leadbolt ad in my app. Problem that it looks ugly.

there is screenshot

[image]

alt text

**advert_activity_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_result_activity"
        >

</FrameLayout>
```

**AdvertActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.Leadbolt.AdController;
import com.alpha_aps.very_hard_game.util.MyActivity;

public class AdvertActivity extends MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.advert_activity_layout);

        AdController myController = new AdController(this, Config.leadBoltInterstitialId);
        myController.loadAd();
    }

}
```

I tried use some different layout such as RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, LinearLayout - no result.
Also I tried play with leadbolt ad settings - use different kind of interstitials - no result also.

**So questions are:**

1. Why interstitial looks with black background?
2. How can I remove this background?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the last Leadbolt SDK
and black background disappear, I do not why.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new ad make sure to check to appearance tab at the top. There is a section here for background color. For a transparent background make sure that this field is empty.

Once an ad has been created I think that the appearance can not be changed so you may need to create a new one.

Alternatively you could set the Overlap Opacity to 100% so that the whole screen around the ad is also black. The field is also located on the appearance tab of your ad creation screen.